# Circle is 6 Inches on Screen, But Not on Printout?

Tags: gimp

I'm using GIMP to make a circle that needs to be 6 inches for a project I'm working on, I made a circle using the ellipse select tool and holding shift. I then used the size parameter to make the ellipse major axis and semi major axis the same forming a circle that is supposed to be 6 inches in diameter. The result when I print it is slightly less than 5 inches though? Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?
[image: Circle]

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct page layout set ? may be A4 ..

Comment: How would I check it? @SeverusTux

Comment: While creating new template, select size of paper. like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtkeK.png

Comment: @SeverusTux I selected A4 in the print screen under page setup, it seems that that's what it was.

Comment: In your print settings you have to disable `image scaling` or `shrink to fit` and make sure size is 100%.

Comment: @heynnema Couldn't find shrink to fit in the print options tabs, size is at 100%